# Google sheets COUNTIF function combined with OR function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I've attached a photo of what I am trying to do below. I need to look at multiple columns and if any of them contain "apple" I need to count that row once. I am having a lot of trouble finding the solution.
Here's a photo of what I am trying to do

[image: Here's a photo of what I am trying to do].

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(N(MMULT(REGEXMATCH(B2:E, "(?i)apple")*1, FLATTEN(COLUMN(B2:E)^0))<>0)))
```

[image]

Comment: did you mean to ignore case? Should be (?i) not (i?). Or I guess B2:E="apple" would have worked.